# URLScheme for Salesforce Mobile (iOS)

Tags: mobile, ios

We have an iOS app and I'd like to link to a Salesforce record in the Salesforce Mobile app rather than sending the user to Safari.

Does the Salesforce Mobile app have a URLScheme so that 1) we can check if the app is installed and 2) we can link to a record in that app?

An example of this kind of thing is what Google did in there Google Maps app for iOS. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme. I'd like something analygous to that, but with Salesforce Mobile

Comment: It is an excellent idea, but I have not heard it exists.  I'll ask around - but I'd highly recommend putting it up on ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I would download source code for ForcePad to see how they do it.  ForcePad was created by Salesforce Labs group and is an open source.

https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ForcePad

Comment: Hi, I wrote ForcePad. I don't support a custom URL scheme to launch ForcePad, nor does the standard iPhone app about which hemmeter is asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been informed you might try the:

chatter://

faux-tocal as a possibility.