# Open Salesforce1 ios app with UrlScheme

Tags: salesforce1-app, ios, url

I've been looking for opening iOS Salesforce1 app with UrlScheme.

I found these links : [link1](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001qep&fId=0D53000001Qji5x&elq_mid=5669&elq_cid=5857072)
[link2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7246/urlscheme-for-salesforce-mobile-ios) but they didn't work for me.

I have a links for my VisualForce page (link down below)
Is there any way to open VisualForce page on Salesforce1 iOS app (or any similar approach to this problem ).

https://xxxx.xxxx.visual.force.com/apex/ABCD?IAId=xxxx00000CwFVA&UsId=xxxx000001FpNh&AQId=xxxx00000HCDot

Thanks in advance. Have a good day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce1 makes a few assumptions about where your custom Visualforce pages can be surfaced, and does not support the ability to link to a page via the /apex/MyPage syntax. The places where Visualforce can be surfaced include:

> - The Navigation menu, via a Visualforce tab
> - The publisher, via a custom action
> - Mobile cards on a record’s related information page
> - Overridden standard buttons, or custom buttons and links
> - Embedded in record detail page layouts